# Choose documentclass according to condition

Tags: conditionals, document-configuration

I would like to choose the documentclass according to a value. For instance, something like this

```
\newcommand{\mode}{0}

if (mode is 0)
then \documentclass{...}
else if (mode is 1)
then \documentclass{---}
fi
```

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: Yes of course but this really doesn't make a lot of sense: the document class defines what may and may not be in the content ...

Comment: Yes you're right, actually it's not to choose the documentclass but rather the options and some package that have to be included or not.

Comment: @JosephWright I disagree.  I have a customized class for producing our organizational reports.  But if I want to convert it into a journal manuscript, I replace the customized documentclass with `article` **PLUS** a package that does the conversion of the customized macros into something reasonable.  In this way, by this simple change, I can totally revamp the total look of the document in a consistent way.

Comment: `beamer` versus `beamerarticle` would be another example.

Answer (score 8):

I revised my MWE to answer some of the criticisms about the difficulties encountered by having a selectable document class.  In the MWE, if I choose the `article` class, I also redefine other things (in this case `\chapter`) to make it compatible with the alternate class, which is `book` in this case.

With such an extended approach, one can quickly alternate between custom and standard classes, if one takes the time to redefine a logical way to handle the custom macros.

```
\def\mode{1}
\if 0\mode
  \documentclass{article}
  \let\chapter\section
\else
  \documentclass{book}
\fi
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is my chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If one wants a more descriptive multi-character mode name, then one could do this:

```
\def\mode{ArticleMode}
\def\ArticleMode{%
  \documentclass{article}
  \let\chapter\section
}
\def\BookMode{%
  \documentclass{book}
}
\csname\mode\endcsname
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is my chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this syntax of `if` to compare two values...

Comment: @minomic The use of `\if` compares a two successive bytes.  If you wanted to compare two-digit modes (e.g., `\def\mode{11}`), you would have to use `\ifnum` as shown in Christian's answer.  But with `\if`, the modes could be called `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. instead of numbers.

Comment: I see... And what if I want to compare strings? Like `\newcommand{\mode}{firstMode}` and then `if (mode is firstMode)`

Comment: @minomic See the addition to my answer.

Comment: @minomic To answer your direct question, one can use features of the `ifthen` package, for example, to compare strings.  However, in a case such as this, one cannot load a package without first specifying a document class, so I need to develop an alternate way, as detailed in my second approach.

Comment: Yes, I tried with the `ifthen` package but in my case it could not help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: `\RequirePackage{ifthen}` should work even before `\documentclass`. The LaTeX core is active at that time of loading already. `\usepackage{ifthen}` does not work (as far as I know)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Thanks.  That is good to know.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Some 'hidden' knowledge on a strange site named TeX.SE ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Possible: yes, but it's necessary to change it most times by hand anyway.

The main culprit is that different classes provide different features and some of them are contradictory to each other,i.e. one has to make conditionals to choose the correct settings afterwards anyway.

```
\newcommand{\mode}{1}

\ifnum\mode=0
\documentclass{article}
\else
\documentclass{book}
\fi


\begin{document}


Foo

\ifnum\mode>0
\chapter{Foo}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Here's a way with `\ifcase`

```
\newcommand{\mode}{3}

\ifcase\mode
\documentclass{article}
\or \documentclass{report} % 1
\else
\documentclass{book} % Default 
\fi


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\ifnum\mode>0
\chapter{Foo}
\else
\section{Foo}
\fi
\end{document}
```

**Update** -- with `etoolbox`

It is possible to use `\RequirePackage{...}` even before `\documentclass` but not `\usepackage{...}` -- there are cases where this might be really necessary, but in general I don't recommend this procedure.

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\def\mode{artmode}

\ifstrequal{\mode}{artmode}{%
  \documentclass{article}
}{%
  \documentclass{report}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd go with the `\ifcase` model, that's much more flexible. I'd also use `\providecommand{\mode}{<number>}` in the top line, so the value can be also set in the command line: `pdflatex '\newcommand\mode{2}\input{filename}'` (so without changing the file, which is also possible, of course).